# T-SQL Syntax error - Can´t find where I´m doing wrong

Tags: sql, t-sql

I´m trying to add some extra info to an existing report and the SQL query requires me to add a INNER JOIN referencing an extra table.

I´m not a SQL guru, just know the basics, so I´m strugling to find hwere I´m creating a syntax error in this query.

Below a picture comparing the current working code (Left side) and the faulty code (Right) - The error I get is **'Syntax error in FROM clause'**

[image]

Can anyone please take a look into this and tell me where I´m introducing the syntax error?

Not sure if it helps, but this is the faulty code:

```
SELECT ToolLists.Ident, 
    ToolLists.Descript AS TLDescript, 
    ToolLists.MaterialNr, 
    ToolLists.Order,
    ToolLists.Who, 
    ToolLists.NCP, 
    ToolLists.Rem      AS TLRem, 
    ToolLists.MDate,
    ToolLists.TDate, 
    ToolLists.GDate,
    ToolList.T, 
    Machines.Name      AS MachineName, 
    Machines.TRelation, 
    ToolList.D, 
    ToolList.H, 
    ToolList.Pos       AS ToolListPos, 
    ToolList.Rem       AS ToolListRem, 
    ToolList.How       AS ToolListHow, 
    Tools.Nr, 
    Tools.Z1, 
    Tools.Drawing, 
    Tools.X1, 
    Tools.Sort,
    Tools.Design,
    Tools.Descript,
    Tools.Rem          AS ToolRem, 
    ToolParts.Pos      AS ToolPartPos, 
    ToolParts.Nbr, 
    ToolParts.How, 
    Parts.UNr, 
    Parts.MID,
    Parts.Descript,
    Parts.Sort,
    Parts.Design,
    Parts.URem,
    Parts.DMC,
    Parts.CLength, 
    Parts.CMainArc, 
    Parts.CRadius, 
    Parts.UActiv,
    MatClasses.DMC,
    MatClasses.Description, 
    MatClasses.Quality, 
    NoteParts.NoteText,
    SP.Place
    FROM   (Parts 
    RIGHT JOIN ((Machines 
                    RIGHT JOIN ((MatClasses 
                    RIGHT JOIN (Materials 
RIGHT JOIN ((SELECT ID, 
    Param1 
    FROM   WTDIDList 
    WHERE  WTGUID = '8c68ba58-5ad5-4a13-9bd4-0c4d1109d7c8' 
                                           ) 
                                           AS IDList 
                                            INNER JOIN ToolLists 
                                                    ON IDList.ID = 
                                                       ToolLists.Nr) 
                                        ON Materials.Nr = 
                                           ToolLists.MaterialNr) 
                            ON MatClasses.Nr = Materials.MatClassNr) 
                                INNER JOIN (Tools 
                                            INNER JOIN ToolList 
                                                    ON Tools.Nr = 
                                                       ToolList.ToolNr) 
                                        ON ToolLists.Nr = ToolList.ToolListNr) 
                            ON Machines.Nr = ToolLists.MachineNr) 
                   INNER JOIN ToolParts 
                           ON Tools.Nr = ToolParts.ToolNr) 
               ON Parts.ID = ToolParts.PartID)
                   INNER JOIN NoteParts
                           ON ToolParts.PartID = NoteParts.Nr)
               ON Parts.ID = ToolParts.PartID)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT PartId, Place FROM SiteParts WHERE SiteNr = 1) AS SP ON SP.PartId = Parts.Id
ORDER  BY ToolLists.Nr, 
          ToolList.Pos, 
          ToolList.T;
```

Comment: Write your code so each `JOIN` has a matching `ON`.

Comment: Right join misses two left parens.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I´m sorry, don´t want to sound lazy or disrespectful, but I´m not following you... Could you please comment the code or share a short example?

Comment: @Arvo I added two left parenthesis to RIGHT JOIN ((((SELECT ID, and now I get a 'Syntax error in JOIN operation'

Comment: Yeah, your join structure is rather complex. Initially you added two joins (with unmatched parenthesises at right side), but where they start? Apparently not at RIGHT JOIN clause, but somewhere later. Refomat your query to indent all joined tables/joins properly and you likely will see, where left parenthesis is missing. Sorry, this is not answer, just hint, in what direction to search.

Comment: Not clear what the business purpose of this is.   I suspect there is a simpler solution.

Comment: Hi @Paparazzi this is a report that is provided with an application we use here. I didn´t write it, actually my current skill set don´t allow me to go that far. I´m just trying to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are to many or not enough closing parenthesizes.  I have formatted it a bit and think this is what you were trying to accomplish.  This should get rid of the syntax error.  Hopefully it returns the results you are looking for.

> --change the SELECT * the actual select statement.

```
SELECT *
FROM   (Parts 
    RIGHT JOIN (
        (Machines 
            RIGHT JOIN (
                (MatClasses 
                    RIGHT JOIN (Materials 
                        RIGHT JOIN (
                            (SELECT ID, Param1 FROM   WTDIDList WHERE  WTGUID = '8c68ba58-5ad5-4a13-9bd4-0c4d1109d7c8' ) AS IDList 
                            INNER JOIN ToolLists ON IDList.ID = ToolLists.Nr
                        ) 
                    ON Materials.Nr = ToolLists.MaterialNr
                    ) 
                ON MatClasses.Nr = Materials.MatClassNr
                ) 
                INNER JOIN (Tools 
                INNER JOIN ToolList 
                    ON Tools.Nr = ToolList.ToolNr
                ) 
        ON ToolLists.Nr = ToolList.ToolListNr
            ) 
        ON Machines.Nr = ToolLists.MachineNr
        ) 
        INNER JOIN ToolParts 
            ON Tools.Nr = ToolParts.ToolNr
    ) 
    INNER JOIN NoteParts
        ON ToolParts.PartID = NoteParts.Nr
         ON Parts.ID = ToolParts.PartID
 )
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT PartId, Place FROM SiteParts WHERE SiteNr = 1) AS SP ON SP.PartId = Parts.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

This section in red is OK

```
NoteParts.NoteText,
```

This section has a wrong sintax if you analize it in conjunction with the entire FROM clause, too many closing marks ")" wrong location, duplicate ON, etc.

```
INNER JOIN NoteParts
                           ON ToolParts.PartID = NoteParts.Nr)
               ON Parts.ID = ToolParts.PartID)
```

I modified this part so it should work well for you

```
SELECT *         FROM   (Parts 
        RIGHT JOIN ((Machines 
                        RIGHT JOIN ((MatClasses 
                        RIGHT JOIN (Materials 
    RIGHT JOIN ((SELECT ID, 
        Param1 
        FROM   WTDIDList 
        WHERE  WTGUID = '8c68ba58-5ad5-4a13-9bd4-0c4d1109d7c8' 
                                               ) 
                                               AS IDList 
                                                INNER JOIN ToolLists 
                                                        ON IDList.ID = 
                                                           ToolLists.Nr) 
                                            ON Materials.Nr = 
                                               ToolLists.MaterialNr) 
                                ON MatClasses.Nr = Materials.MatClassNr) 
                                    INNER JOIN (Tools 
                                                INNER JOIN ToolList 
                                                        ON Tools.Nr = 
                                                           ToolList.ToolNr) 
                                            ON ToolLists.Nr = ToolList.ToolListNr) 
                                ON Machines.Nr = ToolLists.MachineNr) 
                       INNER JOIN ToolParts ON Tools.Nr = ToolParts.ToolNr
                       INNER JOIN NoteParts ON ToolParts.PartID = NoteParts.Nr) 
                   ON Parts.ID = ToolParts.PartID)
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT PartId, Place FROM SiteParts WHERE SiteNr = 1) AS SP ON SP.PartId = Parts.Id
    ORDER  BY ToolLists.Nr, 
              ToolList.Pos, 
              ToolList.T;
```

And here you have the entire query so just copy paste.

```
SELECT ToolLists.Ident, 
    ToolLists.Descript AS TLDescript, 
    ToolLists.MaterialNr, 
    ToolLists.Order,
    ToolLists.Who, 
    ToolLists.NCP, 
    ToolLists.Rem      AS TLRem, 
    ToolLists.MDate,
    ToolLists.TDate, 
    ToolLists.GDate,
    ToolList.T, 
    Machines.Name      AS MachineName, 
    Machines.TRelation, 
    ToolList.D, 
    ToolList.H, 
    ToolList.Pos       AS ToolListPos, 
    ToolList.Rem       AS ToolListRem, 
    ToolList.How       AS ToolListHow, 
    Tools.Nr, 
    Tools.Z1, 
    Tools.Drawing, 
    Tools.X1, 
    Tools.Sort,
    Tools.Design,
    Tools.Descript,
    Tools.Rem          AS ToolRem, 
    ToolParts.Pos      AS ToolPartPos, 
    ToolParts.Nbr, 
    ToolParts.How, 
    Parts.UNr, 
    Parts.MID,
    Parts.Descript,
    Parts.Sort,
    Parts.Design,
    Parts.URem,
    Parts.DMC,
    Parts.CLength, 
    Parts.CMainArc, 
    Parts.CRadius, 
    Parts.UActiv,
    MatClasses.DMC,
    MatClasses.Description, 
    MatClasses.Quality, 
    NoteParts.NoteText,
    SP.Place
    FROM   (Parts 
    RIGHT JOIN ((Machines 
                    RIGHT JOIN ((MatClasses 
                    RIGHT JOIN (Materials 
RIGHT JOIN ((SELECT ID, 
    Param1 
    FROM   WTDIDList 
    WHERE  WTGUID = '8c68ba58-5ad5-4a13-9bd4-0c4d1109d7c8' 
                                           ) 
                                           AS IDList 
                                            INNER JOIN ToolLists 
                                                    ON IDList.ID = 
                                                       ToolLists.Nr) 
                                        ON Materials.Nr = 
                                           ToolLists.MaterialNr) 
                            ON MatClasses.Nr = Materials.MatClassNr) 
                                INNER JOIN (Tools 
                                            INNER JOIN ToolList 
                                                    ON Tools.Nr = 
                                                       ToolList.ToolNr) 
                                        ON ToolLists.Nr = ToolList.ToolListNr) 
                            ON Machines.Nr = ToolLists.MachineNr) 
                   INNER JOIN ToolParts ON Tools.Nr = ToolParts.ToolNr
                   INNER JOIN NoteParts ON ToolParts.PartID = NoteParts.Nr) 
               ON Parts.ID = ToolParts.PartID)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT PartId, Place FROM SiteParts WHERE SiteNr = 1) AS SP ON SP.PartId = Parts.Id
ORDER  BY ToolLists.Nr, 
          ToolList.Pos, 
          ToolList.T;
```

Comment: Hi @victorhugoterceros - Thanks for chiming in.... With your suggested code now I get the error "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Tools.Nr = ToolParts.ToolNr
                   INNER JOIN NoteParts ON ToolParts.PartID = NoteParts.Nr'."